# YouTube API returning correct results in Postman, but outdated results with PHP cURL

Tags: php, http, curl, youtube-api, postman

When I call the YouTube V3 API for a list of videos by playlist ID, I get the correct results when calling the API via Postman, but outdated results (missing today's newly uploaded video) when calling the API via cURL with PHP. I think maybe I am getting cached results with cURL but I don't know why that would be the case.

My PHP code:

```php
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=$playlistId&key=$api_key&maxResults=50");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        "Cache-Control: no-cache"
    ));
    $json = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

My Postman request:

Type: GET

URL: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=(playlist-id)&key=(api-key)&maxResults=50